# systemjs - "system.import" fails if file contains "use strict"

Tags: javascript, systemjs

I would like to use systemjs as a module loader in a new project. Everything works fine until I add 'use strict'; to the top of the file which should be loaded.

script.js

```
System.import('loadme.js').then(function(m) {
    console.log('loaded');
    console.log(app);
})
```

loadme.js

```
'use strict'; //if I remove this line the import works fine
var app={
  version:'0.0.0',
  name:'just a test'
};
```

I have a plunkr here https://plnkr.co/edit/bhSTkcZw9XaKszXuIYZQ

Comment: Found an issue in the system.js project about exactly this issue https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/issues/75 but it looks like it has been closed as fixed from as far back as 2014

Comment: Ok, thanks - I rise an issue in the project tracker. I will update on SO when I receive an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's expecting a module to be passed back with the data, and not a global variable (see documentation on [strict mode globals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#Converting_mistakes_into_errors)).

Here's something you could do, if you just want it to work:
https://plnkr.co/edit/pVKqfGkcCagyLixtmziB?p=preview

```
'use strict';

var app = {
  version: '0.0.0',
  name: 'just a test'
};

module.exports = app;

/*
  You can also do

  module.exports = {
    app: app,
    foo: foo,
    bar: bar
    .
    .
    .
  }

  and then in your script.js have module.app, module.foo

*/
```

Comment: You are a genius! Thank you. Do you have some more information on this? The link you sent me does not talk about "module".

Comment: No problem. I find this gives a pretty good explanation of exports and modules for importing in commonJS - http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/

Comment: ...and javascript (see tags).  Also, because he/she asked?